# Java find “stain” in multidimensional - recursive

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to solve this Recursive Exercise:

In a multidimensional board (M x N), which everyone of his elements can be empty or full.

"stain" size is the number of elements who are next to each other and has the value 'x'.

for example this is a multidimensional array (the numbers are the row/column number)

```
  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
0 |   | x |   |   | x |
1 | x |   |   | x | x |
2 |   |   | x | x |   |
3 | x |   |   |   |   |
4 | x | x | x |   |   |
```

There are 3 stains:

- Rows (0,1), (1,0) - Size of 2
- Rows (0 ,4) ,(1 ,3) ,(1 ,4) ,(2 ,2) ,(2 ,3) - Size 5
- Rows (3 ,0) ,(4 ,0) ,(4 ,1) ,(4 ,2) - Size 4

We need to write a recursive method who has a signature of:

```
public static int stain (char [][] mat, int row, int col)
```

the method will get a row and a column and calculate the stain size from that place, if there is no stain it will return 0.

I tried to write the method to solve it but looks like I was doing it kinda messy... can you direct me to the right direction? I'm not looking for a straight answer.

Thanks.
I can't do loops!

Comment: Are you allowed to change the `mat` matrix during the recursive call execution for the backtracking purposes? Welcome to SO, btw :)

Comment: "I tried to write the method to solve it but looks like I was doing it kinda messy" -- please share your code so we know what we're dealing with here. Does your code not work or are you looking for a code review? See also [695. Max Area of Island](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-area-of-island/) which is a slight variant on this and has a thread with hundreds of solutions you can look at.

Comment: thanks Mark, and I published my code, I will happy to review my code and direct me what missing.